# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException

Tags: android, sdk

I'm using Android Studio for the first time and I got the following error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
    > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

build.gradle:

```
 dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile project(':tag-cloud')
        compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.8.0@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }
        compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.1.jar')
        compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-s3-2.2.6.jar')
        compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-core-2.2.6.jar')
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
        compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.6.0'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
        compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.6'
        compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
        compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
        compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
        compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
        compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-6.2.0.jar')
        compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.3@aar'
    }
```

Do you have any idea what the problem could be and how can it be solved? A good explanation for the problem would be useful too as I am new to Android Studio. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: See this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460443/execution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-com-android-ide-common-process-proces . It may help.

Comment: Clean the project and build again, chances are that some stale files have been left over

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917696/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-com-android-ide-common-process)

Comment: Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416383/execution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug/34417189#34417189 Refer this solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This options may solve the issue**

- Clean The Project
- Remove all unused dependencies in `build.gradle`
- **If not solved then Declare this in gradle config.**

  defaultConfig {

  ```
  multiDexEnabled true
  ```

  }

Comment: Cleaned the project and added multiDexEnabled true. but issue not solved. get same error

Comment: It is sure that this problem is raised because of your dependencies. make sure you have files in your libs that are specified in compile files command. And check each line of compilation in your dependencies.

Comment: Next option is Try updating some of them if it won't affect codes like de.hdodenhof:circleimageview is now 2.0.0.